# Terminating MySQL ALTER command will erase my data?

Tags: mysql

I am using SQLyog to access my remote MySQL databases. I have altered a table from GUI to add one column with default value 0 which is taking too long to finish with 39K records only. It's been 5 hours now. What should I do? Will I lose data if I terminate this process forcefully?

Please guide me what to do? I am worried.

Thank you!

Comment: If you try to terminate your ALTER TABLE then the operation will be not terminated but rollbacked (from the practice - this needs at least twice time).

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?  The old `ALTER` would create a new table, then swap the new copy into place.  Abort was very quick and mostly safe.

Comment: @RickJames I am aletring table from GUI not with query. Version am using is SQLyoq ultimate - MYSQL GUI v13.1.1.

Comment: @RickJames is there any difference by altering table from command vs directly from GUI?

Comment: @FelixTenn - I doubt it.  Every UI and API I know of generates an SQL statement and executes that.  If you cannot "see" the actual query, you cannot know what options it tacked on.  Find out the MySQL version -- I would expect 8.0 or 5.7 or older 5.x.

Comment: To be clear, Rick is asking for the version of MySQL Server. You can get this by running `SELECT VERSION();` in any client. SQLyog is only a client, the client does not determine how SQL statements are executed in the server.